# How to put dynamic content in YUI gallery-tooltip for bootstrap

Tags: twitter-bootstrap, tooltip, yui

bootstrap-tooltip" from http://jshirley.github.com/bootstrap/javascript.html#tooltips and I want to dynamically put content when someone enters some incorrect input in the input field.

This is how I am trying it:

```
<script>
var v=new Y.Bootstrap.Tooltip({ selector : '*[rel=tooltip]',trigger:'focus',placement:'right' }).render();
</script>
```

My html part:

```
<input type="text" class="form-control" placeholder="First Name" required="" id="firstNameId" rel="tooltip"/>
```

Now how can I put the content in the tooltip dynamically.